# MongoDB query a document with designated subdocs

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a collection contains documents like below. Categories can contain zero or more category. Each category has name and _boost value. How can I make a query to return document(s) with two or more designated categories. For example: "Sports" and "Science".

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5177492b68dc160d29f13af8"),
  "categories" : [{
      "name" : "Sports",
      "_boost" : 1.0
    }, {
      "name" : "Science",
      "_boost" : 1.5
    }],
  "createTime" : ISODate("2013-04-24T02:53:31.635Z"),
  "srcUri" : "file:/C:/Work/notes.pdf",
  "summary" : "Blah blah",
  "title" : "Hello",
}
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by myself:

```
{
    "categories.name": {$all: ["Science", "Sports"] }
}
```